# Using memcpy with a unique_ptr to a vector

Tags: c++

I am writing a piece of code, where I need to copy a pointer to a vector or some part of it - defined as:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>> filtered_profile_ptr = 
  std::make_unique<std::vector<unsigned int>>((int)baselength);
```

to another pointer to a vector - defined as:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>> profile_vector = 
  std::make_unique<std::vector<unsigned int>>(length + filter_size - 1);
```

I am doing that using the memcpy function - like this:

```
memcpy(&(*profile_vector)[0], &(*profileVector)[length - win_size_left], win_size_left * sizeof(unsigned int));
memcpy(&(*profile_vector)[win_size_left], &(*profileVector)[0], length * sizeof(unsigned int));
memcpy(&(*profile_vector)[length + win_size_left], &(*profileVector)[0], win_size_right * sizeof(unsigned int));
```

My question is: Does using memcpy this way provide some hidden problems, concerning memory in some cases, or maybe some problems concerning the buffer.

P.S. The code runs fine, I am only concerned with the problems that can't be seen.

Comment: Pointers (smart or not) to containers are not useful very often. What is the reason you need pointers to vectors?

Comment: Looks okay, but using a pointer to a vector instead of a plain vector is a bit weird and `std::copy` would do the right thing without you having to scratch your head.

Comment: This code is really hard to read and follow. Even if it's correct you're going to have substantial maintenance problems. I suggest reworking it.

Comment: The copying part is written in a different function, to which I am trying to pass the values of vectors.

Comment: `std::vector` has the meber functions `insert` and `append`.  You should be using those t copy elements from one vector to another.  AFAIK, the big three all optimize this to a `memcpy` for POD types.

Comment: I would honestly consider rewriting this without using `std::unique_ptr` (nor any kind of pointer to vector) and without using `memcpy`. Just use `std::vector` and `std::copy` etc. It might even be more efficient without the extra indirection. The resulting code should definitely be less error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is hardly ever a reason to allocate a vector dynamically. You can simplify the program a lot by using automatic storage:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> filtered_profile(baselength);
std::vector<unsigned int> profile_vector(length + filter_size - 1);
```

Hidden problem of `memcpy` is that it only works with trivially copyable types - for others the behaviour is undefined. Sure, your copies may be trivial at the moment (assuming I've read your code correctly in that you're coping the internal buffers of the vectors), but there is no need to rely on that subtle detail: You could use `std::copy` instead which works with non-trivially types as well.

This program should do what your memcpy does, unless I misread your program. Except this works on vectors without smart pointers. This is much more readable, at least to me:

```
assert(std::size(profileVector) >= length);
auto srcB = std::begin(profileVector); // begin
auto srcE = srcB + length;             // end
auto srcL = srcE - win_size_left;      // left from end
auto srcR = srcB + win_size_right;     // right from begin


assert(std::size(profile_vector) >= win_size_left + length + win_size_right);
auto dst0 = std::begin(profile_vector);
auto dst1 = dst0 + win_size_left;
auto dst2 = dst1 + length;

std::copy(srcL, srcE, dst0);
std::copy(srcB, srcE, dst1);
std::copy(srcB, srcR, dst2);
```

P.S. Note that naming two variables `profile_vector` and `profileVector` is highly confusing. Consider renaming one of them. Furthermore, it is unclear how `filtered_profile` is related to the copying.